# The difference between visit, tour and travel

Tags: word-choice

> I ___ a museum yesterday.

Between *toured*, *visited*, and *traveled*, which word better fits in that sentence?

Could the range or number of the places result in a different word choice?

Comment: The words have different meanings, and different grammar.  Have you checked the meaning and grammar in a dictionary?

Comment: You travel to a country on tour and visit places in that country.

Answer (score 1):

> I __________ a museum yesterday.

[Travel](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/zht/%E8%A9%9E%E5%85%B8/%E8%8B%B1%E8%AA%9E/travel) (✖):

We can't use travel here, because we should use travel **to** (place).

For example:

> Tom travels **to** work by train.

[Tour](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/tour_2) (✔):

Tour is correct here, see the example below:

> The princess toured a new nursery school.

Also see: [tour museum](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tour%20museum&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctour%20museum%3B%2Cc0) and [tour the museum](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tour%20the%20museum&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctour%20the%20museum%3B%2Cc0)

[Visit](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/visit) (✔):

Visit is also correct here, needless to say:

> A recent trip to London gave me the opportunity to visit the Science Museum.

Although tour and visit are both appropriate here, **visit** is [more frequently used](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=visit%20the%20museum%2C%20tour%20the%20museum&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cvisit%20the%20museum%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctour%20the%20museum%3B%2Cc0), because it sounds smoother.

Comment: "Tour" implies a more in-depth experience, perhaps with a "tour guide"—a docent who accompanies visitors and provides additional insights.